# How can I handle elements positions in a web application?

Tags: c#, angular

I'm developing a web application where the API is in c# and the front in angular. The front build elements dynamically. This application will be used by many clients and each client needs to display elements from the page on a different position.

Example :

## Client 1 :

### Titre 1

element1

element2

## Client 2 :

### Titre 1

element2

element1

So the question is : how is the proper way to handle elements positions in a web development ? Do I need to return the position of each elements with the API using the appsettings or would the front do it ?

Thank you !

For the moment, I read an appsettings in the API and return a table of data with elements in good position.

Comment: API should handle the positions for elements

Answer (score 0):

if use grid of bootstrap.css you can reorder [reorder grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#reordering), just in Angular use [ngClass] to add `order-1` or `order-12`, e.g. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e3396v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      First, but unordered
    </div>
    <div class="col-12" [ngClass]="{'order-12':!order}">
      Second, but last
    </div>
    <div class="col-12" [ngClass]="{'order-1':!order}">
      Third, but first
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn" (click)="order=!order">Reorder</button>
```